# How to load mat files w/ different names?

Tags: matlab, matrix, load

I have different mat files w/ distinct names. So I am using a function whose input is the mat file. I used "varargin" to enable the function to take different files.

```
 function bestfunc(varargin)
 data = load(varargin, '-mat');
 end
```

when I try to call the function like

> bestfunc('matrix777')

Matlabe comes up w/ this error:

```
Error using load
Argument must contain a string.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `bestfunc('matrix777')` - like the '-mat' part of load you have to put it inside `' '`, otherwise its a variable

Comment: @Finn That just works for "matrix777". What should I do if I want to load "matrix888"? Then I will have to change the code. I don't wanna do that!

Comment: it is possible but you should provide a little more information. are all of those files in the same folder and are there only those files? and is the script in this folder too? hast bestfunc data as an output ?

Comment: @Finn yes they are in the same folder! It does have output. But I do not know how to call different matrices without changing the code! That's the problem.

Comment: What @Finn means is that when you *call* the function, you should use `bestfunc('matrix777')` with single quotes, not `bestfunc(matrix777)` like you're doing. Also, since you're only passing *one* argument, you don't need `varargin`. Just use a normal variable name like `matname`.

Comment: @beaker that was a type here. I was using single quotes. BTW, your hint just helped me to do what I wanted :) Please post it as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're only passing *one* argument, you don't need [varargin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html), which is used when you may have a variable number of arguments to a function.

Just use a normal variable name like `matname`:

```
function bestfunc(matname)
   data = load(matname, '-mat');
end
```

Then call it as you did before:

```
bestfunc('matrix777')
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to get the names of the files. You can use `dir()` to do that.

```
dir('*.mat') % will return information about all .mat files in the folder
```

The output is a struct with more information for each file. TO get the names try

```
names=struct2cell(dir('*.mat'));
names=names(1,:);
```

now names is a cellarray with the names of all *.mat files of your folder. TO load data from each go for

```
for i=1:length(names)
    bestfun(names{i});
end
```